# Low & Full-profile bracket

Tags: wireless-networking

If a card has both low and full profile brackets, does that mean it *should* fit in any slot? How would this exactly work though, are there disadvantages to having a card that supports both?

For reference, I was looking at [this network card](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-wireless-n-pci-card-v5-w-full-low-profile-brackets).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should fit in any compatible PCI slot.. your cards profile will either be full height or half height and that size will be dependent on what your computer case needs.